# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'epiz_31603255'@'192.168.%' to database 'srms'

Tags: php

i Have tried to use PDO connection so it's works on localserver but here in CPanel i'm getting the above error

Comment: `192.168.%` looks like an internal IP inside some local network. If you're trying to access that server from the outside (from some hosting server), you would need to expose that internal server to the internet and then use the public IP to connect to it. You would also need to configure that DB user to allow for connections from your external servers IP. You can't connect directly to internal IP's from outside the network.

Comment: i already tried but not fixed

Comment: Please add the error and details in the question not in the header.